# Crystal Reports: ? Possible to show Full Set in one chart, and subsets in separate charts?

Tags: crystal-reports, charts

In Crystal Reports, is there a way to get both full set charting and subset charting, in the report headers?

I'm working on a report from an erstwhile co-worker and I'm still trying to make things "better".

While I haven't found the solution to accruing time 
( see [Accruing over time (non-overlapping) - technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995723/accruing-over-time-non-overlapping-technique) )
I'll press on with how to use the resulting data once I retrieve it.

The report is a Global Availability report for network technologies, and part of the report is graphic:

- Chart availability for different
  network types for last "n" months'
  time.
- Charts availability for each region
  (for each network type for "n"
  months' time).

She (co-worker) had a global chart, but for each region, she did a separate sub-report containing just the chart for that region.  The query isn't optimal, and using the sub-reports, the query is repeated each time.

If there a way to use a single data-set in one report for all five charts, forcing the four regional charts to display only that region's data?

Additional info:
The charts are all Bar charts, design is 
y-axis:  calculated availability 
x-axis:  Group by network type (Switches, Trunks, "Network)
     sub group by month

Bad Example:[image: Global Chart w/ Regional Charts example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand this.  In your Report Header, you have 5 Subreports for the 4 regional graphs and the global graph.  And you want to collapse this all into 1 Subreport if possible?

Yes, but you can't do it like in your image where United States & Europe are side-by-side.  They would have to be 1 per row.  Also, the datasource also has to be formatted correctly.  To do this,

1. Make a new subreport.  Group it by the Region.
2. In this subreport, make your regional graph in the Group Header section.
3. In this subreport, also make your global graph in the Report Header section.
4. Insert this subreport into your main report and you should be done.

Comment: Well, sort of.  I'm maintaining her report, and after long and arduous communications w/ the customer, she did this in bits and pieces -- very hard to maintain, and w/ inconsistent logic.    I thought the same for the rpt header chart and regions in the groups, but she has done something else w/ the groups below and it will mess that up.  (I even figured on doing conditional over-lay section below to make them look side by side.)  I need to get the customer to talk with me or I just need to maintain this in bits and pieces.  I didn't think it could be done easily.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: Scrapping the original report & starting over from scratch is always an option.

Comment: I want to scrap WAY more than anyone knows.  Did I mention that, in additional to the charting issue, there are 41 subreports that were added, many of which are used to calc and pass a single value (from a set-base) back, the report requirement morphed through email direction (not documented -- over a year's time), and that each of the sub-queries is TOTALLY different (logically inconsistent) from anything else?  Oh, and I'm months over-due w/ getting the report out -- and I can't speak w/ the requestor?  Just whining.  It sure would be a great report if I could re-do.

Comment: To quote someone else's signature from another website, "That hideousness is what keeps you and I employed."

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the only way out of the fire is through it.

After lots of un-satisfactory refactoring, I spoke with the original (years ago) requestor and got some good information.  I have yet to speak to the most recent requestor again (who didn't have any knowledge of the technical requirements the last several times).

Spoke w/ the guy who is tending a related db, and I get permission to add come functions, views, store procedures, etc. to THAT db... Within reason and after code/perf review -- something that isn't normally conducted, so I welcome it.  I WILL have the ability to do the procedural stuff through... a procedure.  Written as a stand-alone, I should be able to re-use it for any of the queries against future needs.

And... Yes, I am pretty much going to have to (read "get to") re-design, and hopefully get rid of most of the sub-reports.  Yeay, me.

Thanks for coming along for the ride.